# fast way to apply formula to each row in dataframe using all previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 million rows. I need to apply a formula to each row in the dataframe using all the rows up to the current row.

So to calculate formula output for row with index 20,000, I need to apply the formula to the last 19,999 rows and for row index 30,001 I need to apply formula to last 30,000 rows.

```
#formula uses numpy and uses columns of all the rows fed to it
def formula(col1, col2, col3):
     len_col1 = len(np.unique(col1))
     hf = np.bincount(col1, col2* col3)
     tf = np.sum(hf) / np.sqrt(np.sum(hf ** 2)) * np.sqrt(250 / len_col1 )
     y = np.clip(tf , 0, 6) * np.sum(hf )
     return y
```

I am currently attempting to do this by iterating each row but the runtime or each row has a cumulative effect as the formula is applied to more rows as we iterate. This cannot be applied as it'll likely take 10 days+. I iterate the main `train_df` dataframe while also appending each row to a `first_batch` dataframe which is used to calculate output of formula before and after the current row is appended.

```
first_batch = train_df.head(7)
train_df["formula_3"] = 0

#for index, row in train_df.iloc[8:].iterrows():

for index, row in tqdm(train_df.iterrows(), total=train_df.shape[0]):
    #print(index)
    formula_1 = formula(first_batch['col1'], first_batch['col2'], first_batch['col3'])
    
    first_batch = first_batch.append(row, ignore_index=False)

    formula_2 = formula(first_batch['col1'], first_batch['col2'], first_batch['col3'])
   
    train_df.loc[index, "formula_3"] =  formula_2 - formula_1
```

I know the key maybe using numpy, vectorization or `.apply()` function but I am not experienced in python and unable to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: unless you show what is the formula, there is no way to see if it can be vectorized. There are things that cannot and inherently a hard computational task. that said, append to DF is expensive, you better create empty rows and update on them.

Comment: @BingWang added formula

Comment: did you try a simple iterrows without any calculation to see if time is acceptable? Your calculation can be done in O(1) for each row: unique is can be done by adding one element into a counter dicitonary. sum(hf) is same as index so you can avoid it. sum(hf**2) is a bit tricky: you need to maintain a running total add (2*new_count+1) for the current row's col1 count (because ((N+1)**2-N**2=2N+1). Basically your original program is O(N2) and it can be improved to O(N) with df.apply